# Column with strings and numbers to column only with numbers

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

I have a column with strings and numbers as you can see in the image below (4th column):

[image: column string and number]

I want to compute a series "wavelength" where I only have the numbers. I did not find any help anywhere.

Comment: thankks @Gary's Student

Answer (score 0):

Bit of research would have gone a long way.

`=COUNT()` counts numerical values
`=SUM()` sums numerical values

If you have literally tried the most basic of solutions, it would have worked.

---

Alternatively you can add an extra column and use the following formula

```
=IF(ISNUM(A1), A1, 0)
```

which will convert all non-numerical values to 0.

Comment: I will try to search more next time.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through numbers only with SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim r As Range, rng As Range
    With Worksheets("Input")
        Set rng = .Columns("D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
        For Each r In rng
            Debug.Print r.Value2
            'do something with the value of r besides printing it to the VBE's Immediqte window
        Next r
    End With
End Sub

 250.1 
 337.7 
 414.6 
 293.2 
 361.7
```

Comment: Thanks, I have checked and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a column of mixed data like:

[image]

and we want to extract only the numeric values.  In **B1** enter:

```
=MIN(A1:A24)
```

In **B2** enter the **array formula**:

```
=IF(MIN(IF(A$1:A$24>B1,A$1:A$24))<B1,"",MIN(IF(A$1:A$24>B1,A$1:A$24)))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

The formula gets the numeric values and arranges them in sorted order!

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

Comment: Thank you so much, great formula